# Inverting a matrix with the same diagonal entries in a particular form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Hi I'm struggling with this inversion and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to invert the following $\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 + m       & m & \dots & \dots & m \\
    m       & 1+m & m & \dots & m\\
    \dots & \dots &\dots & \dots & \dots\\
    m       & m & m & \dots & 1 +m
\end{bmatrix} such that it is of the following form: $I - \gamma \textbf{u}\textbf{u}^T$ for a constant $\gamma$ that I need to find, and $\textbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^m. $

So the matrix to invert is square and has $1+m$ in all its diagonal entries and $m$ everywhere else, not sure if there is a special way to invert such a matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is $\gamma=\frac{m}{m^2+1}$.

When writing out the product of the matrix that needs to be inverted with the proposed form of the inverse:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 + m       & m & \dots & m \\
    m       & 1+m & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \ddots &\ddots & m\\
    m       & \dots & m & 1 +m
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1-\gamma       & -\gamma & \dots & -\gamma \\
    -\gamma       & 1-\gamma & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \ddots &\ddots & -\gamma\\
    -\gamma       & \dots & -\gamma & 1-\gamma
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0       & 1 & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \ddots &\ddots & 0\\
    0       & \dots & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
you'll notice that for each diagonal element of the resulting identity matrix, you have
\begin{equation}
(1+m)(1-\gamma) + (m-1) m (-\gamma) = 1
\end{equation}
while on the off-diagonal, you have
\begin{equation}
m (1-\gamma) + (1+m)(-\gamma) + (m-2)m(-\gamma) = 0
\end{equation}
Both equations have the same solution for $\gamma$, namely $\gamma=\frac{m}{m^2+1}$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense i don't know why i never thought to do that myself, thanks again for your help.